# Change color of specific points in scatter3 by a variable

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, matlab-figure

I have a matrix with 4 columns and about 1000 rows. The first three columns are the `X,Y,Z` coordinates, the fourth column is a factor variable(0 or 1).

I want to plot these `X,Y,Z` coordinates in 3D, where all the coordinates whose corresponding fourth column is '0' in green, and all the coordinates whose corresponding fourth column is '1' in red.

How to specify this in `scatter3`?

Answer (score 0):

```
scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C)
```

From the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html). Plot your `X,Y,Z`, specify some circle-size for the `S` parameter, and use your fourth columns as `C`:

```
YourMat = rand(1e3,4); %// create random data
YourMat(:,4) = round(YourMat(:,4)); %// round 4th clomun to binary
scatter3(YourMat(:,1),YourMat(:,2),YourMat(:,3),5,YourMat(:,4)) %// scatter3 the thing
colormap(jet) %// for the red/blue and because jet is the best
```

[image]